# How to add multipile views and delete view and get all the data from the the views after deleting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to create multiple views with one text field, now I have to create multiple view when I click on the the + button and if you click on - button,the view must delete. I did using this code.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
IBOutlet UITableView *viewsTbl;
IBOutlet UIButton *addBtn;
NSMutableArray *countArr;
NSMutableDictionary *dataArr;
NSInteger number;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
countArr = [NSMutableArray array];
dataArr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dataArr setValue:@"" forKey:@"TextFieldOne"];
[dataArr setValue:@"" forKey:@"TextFieldTwo"];
[countArr addObject:dataArr];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return  countArr.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ViewTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewTableViewCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (countArr.count == indexPath.row+1)
{
    cell.buttonPlus.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
    cell.buttonPlus.hidden = YES;

}
NSDictionary *dict = countArr[indexPath.row];
cell.txtFldOne.text = dict[@"TextFieldOne"];
cell.txtFldTwo.text = dict[@"TextFieldTwo"];

cell.txtFldTwo.delegate = self;
cell.txtFldOne.delegate = self;
cell.txtFldOne.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.txtFldTwo.tag = indexPath.row+1000;
[cell.buttonPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(plusBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.buttonMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(minusBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 150;
}

-(void)plusBtnClick
{
dataArr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dataArr setValue:@"" forKey:@"TextFieldOne"];
[dataArr setValue:@"" forKey:@"TextFieldTwo"];
[countArr addObject:dataArr];
[viewsTbl reloadData];

}
-(IBAction)minusBtnClick:(id)sender
{
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:viewsTbl];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [viewsTbl indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
[countArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[viewsTbl reloadData];
if (countArr.count == 0)
{
    addBtn.hidden = NO;
    viewsTbl.hidden = YES;

}
else
{
    addBtn.hidden = YES;
    viewsTbl.hidden = NO;

}

}
-(IBAction)addBtnClick:(id)sender
{
dataArr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dataArr setValue:@"" forKey:@"TextFieldOne"];
[dataArr setValue:@"" forKey:@"TextFieldTwo"];
[countArr addObject:dataArr];
addBtn.hidden = YES;
viewsTbl.hidden = NO;
[viewsTbl reloadData];
}
```

Now the problem is, I am adding a button called print in the view controller and click on it the data entered in the text fields must add to either dictionary or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also save data using text filed  delegates

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

CGPoint buttonPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:viewsTbl];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [viewsTbl indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
dataArr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:countArr[indexPath.row]];
 NSMutableDictionary *datadict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
if (number == indexPath.row)
{
    [datadict setValue:text forKey:@"TextFieldOne"];
    [datadict setValue:dataArr[@"TextFieldTwo"] forKey:@"TextFieldTwo"];

}
else if(number == indexPath.row +1000)
{
    [datadict setValue:dataArr[@"TextFieldOne"] forKey:@"TextFieldOne"];
    [datadict setValue:text forKey:@"TextFieldTwo"];

}
[countArr replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:datadict];

return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 number = textField.tag;
}
```